# A value of type 'PickedFile?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

when i try to import 'dart.io' i face this problem or when i delete 'dart.io' i face undefined class 'File'

```dart
File file;
  getPhoto() async {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  File file =  await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxHeight: 675,
      maxWidth: 960,
    );
  }
~~~!
```

Answer (score 1):

`pickImage` returns a `PickedFile?` and not `File`

Use this to get a file:

```
  File? file;
  getPhoto() async {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    final pickedImage = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxHeight: 675,
      maxWidth: 960,
    );
    if(pickedImage != null){
      file = File(pickedImage.path);
    }
  }
```